# Triangle inequality with a twist

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Assume $t>0$ and $x,y,z\in [0,t)$ how would one go about showing
$$\min \{|x-y|,t-|x-y|\}\leq\min \{|x-z|,t-|x-z|\}+\min \{|z-y|,t-|z-y|\} $$
If the first one materializes from every minimum, then there would be no problem, standard triangle inequality. However, what if all the minima are the second one:
$$t-|x-y|\leq t-|x-z|+t-|z-y|\Leftrightarrow |x-y|\geq |x-z|+|z-y| $$
which in case of equality poses no problem, but if $>$, then it's contradicting. Can the initial situation ever occur, is another thing to consider.

The question is: can we efficiently verify the validity of this inequality or do we have to consider each case?

Assumption by contradiction doesn't help with reducing the quantity of cases to be considered. Not looking for a full solution, rather hints to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to have all the minimums from the second part. As you asked I am just giving hint. To have all the minimums from the second part the following inequalities hold

$$
t-\mid x-y\mid\leq \mid x-y\mid\\
t-\mid x-z\mid \leq \mid x-z\mid \\
t-\mid z-y\mid\leq \mid z-y\mid
$$
Now these three imply all differences and  $x,y,z\in[0,t)$ would give you a contradiction.

Comment: @AlvinLepik The case $t-\mid x-y\mid \leq t-\mid x-z\mid +\mid z-y\mid $ is another triangle inequality which is $\mid x-z \mid \leq \mid x-y\mid +\mid y-z\mid $. The  problem is having all minimums from the second part and I mentioned a way to eliminate it.

Comment: if all minimums give the second one then
$$\begin{cases}|x-y|\geq t/2\\|x-z|\geq t/2\end{cases}\Rightarrow\begin{cases}x\geq t/2+y\\ x\leq-t/2+z\end{cases}\Rightarrow z-y\geq t$$ absurd

Comment: There are other ways to see that as well, but your are right. So, once you eliminate that possibility the other cases boil down to triangle inequality.

Comment: thank you for bearing with me. I understand now :) 
would like to know what another way of seeing the former result, would be.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different approach:

Let $\delta(x,y) = \min(|x-y|, t-|x-y|)$, where $x,y \in [0,t]$.

For any $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, define $d(x,y) = \min_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} |x-y-nt| = \min_{n_1,n_2 \in \mathbb{Z}} |x-y-n_1t-n_2t|$.

It is straightforward to show that for $x,y \in [0,t]$ that $\delta(x,y) = d(x,y)$.

Then for any $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$ we have
$ |x-y-n_1t-n_2t| = |x-z+z-y-n_1t -n_2t| \le |x-z-n_1t| + |z-y-n_2t| $ and so
$d(x,y) \le |x-z-n_1t| + |z-y-n_2t|$ for any $n_1,n_2$.

Choosing $n_1,n_2$ appropriately, we have
$d(x,y) \le d(x,z)+d(z,y)$.

If $x,y,z \in [0,t]$ this shows that $\delta(x,y) \le \delta(x,z)+\delta(z,y)$.